# How to know number of bars beforehand in Pygal?

Tags: graph, pygal

When plotting a bar graph, for example, using pygal, I'd like to be able to know the number of bars the graph will have, in order to make a decision on whether or not the graph should be plotted.
Is there a way to do this?

Additionally, is there also a way to find out the number of slices in a pygal pie graph, and the number of points in a pygal line graph, before plotting them?

Thanks in advance!